# scss css compilation throwing error on following css

Tags: html, css, compiler-errors, sass

While compling scss, I'm getting error on following css:

```
span.icon-hcp {
        filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/icon-hc.jpg', sizingMethod='scale') !important;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../images/icon-hc.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')" !important;
        background-image: none !important;
    }
```

Error:

```
>>> Change detected to: style.scss
  error style.scss (Line 13838: Invalid CSS after "
  filter: progid": expected ";", was ": DXImageTransf...")
```

I couldn't find whats wrong with the above css code. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space from `progid: DXImageTransform` => `progid:DXImageTransform`

```
span.icon-hcp {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/icon-hc.jpg', sizingMethod='scale') !important;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../images/icon-hc.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')" !important;
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

Comment: @ARUN glad to help